# Is textjoin optimal for writing an arrayformula with variables?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, string-concatenation, textjoin

Desired outout for this formula is

```
={
 ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(

List of names from e.g. A2:A25 like Abraham, Bonaparte, Cassius...

; ", $"; ))}
```

The list of names from A2:A25 must be presented with an If/Else and a comma between more than 1 name like this:

```
 IF('Abraham'!B2:F7<>""; 'Abraham'!A1&", "; )&
 IF('Bonaparte'!B2:F7<>""; 'Bonaparte'!A1; )
```

I have tried and failed with this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({""; "=ARRAYFORMULA({
"&TEXTJOIN(";"; 1;"

={
 ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(
 IF('Abraham'!B2:F7<>""; 'Abraham'!A1&", "; )&
 IF('Bonaparte'!B2:F7<>""; 'Bonaparte'!A1; ); ", $"; ))}

";)
)}
}
```

Any ideas?

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EnxhbS7dp_1sw6Ok_P0P_-fAAwpuGQMICaT5o3tKSuU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This feels a lot like an xy problem. http://xyproblem.info/ Can you provide a little more context about the end goal?

Comment: @MattKing Hi there. I'm afraid player0 answered better than I asked :-) Take a look below for a perfect solution. Thank you for asking.

Comment: Oh yeah, I saw that. It was great!  I was just wondering *why* you wanted that output :) ?

Comment: The short version is that I work with challenged students and I try to automate as many processes as possible for both them and my colleagues. The goal is to constantly reduce the workflow to set the crosses :-)

Comment: Loved xyproblem.info by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
={"";ARRAYFORMULA("=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM("&TEXTJOIN("&"; 1; 
 IF(A1:A<>""; "IFERROR(IF("&A1:A&"!B2:F7<>""""; "&A1:A&
 "!A1&"", ""; ); {""""\""""\""""\""""\""""})"; ))&"); "",$""; ))")}
```

[image: 0]